# TYPO3: How to use storage pid from pagetree in backend module?

Tags: typo3, extbase

I created an extension using Extension Builder, and included a backend module, under the web section. In the generated code, there are two constants for the storage pid: one for plugins and one for modules.

Now I like my module to use the storage pid from the selected page or folder in the pagetree, like page, list, or template modules do. How can I use storage pid from pagetree instead of using a constant, in a backend module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the selected page from the page tree in your backend module, one way is to simply get the `id` param, ideally in your initializer.

Since extbase reads the storage pid from your module (or plugin for the frontend) settings, you can just override the `storagePid` part so you don't have to set the pid for each query / otherwise in your repositories.

The following **should** work. However, I use this in a CommandController and not in a controller used in the backend. I hadn't to change anything there because the repositories automatically scoped records to the selected page.

```
class Tx_MyExt_Controller_BackendController extends Tx_Extbase_MVC_Controller_ActionController {

    /**
     * @var Tx_Extbase_Configuration_ConfigurationManagerInterface
     * @inject 
     */
    protected $configurationManager;

    /**
     * @var int Current page
     */
    protected $pageId;


    /**
     * Action initializer
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function initializeAction()
    {
        $this->pageId = (int)t3lib_div::_GP('id');

        $frameworkConfiguration = $this->configurationManager->getConfiguration(Tx_Extbase_Configuration_ConfigurationManagerInterface::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_FRAMEWORK);
        $persistenceConfiguration = array('persistence' => array('storagePid' => $this->pageId));
        $this->configurationManager->setConfiguration(array_merge($frameworkConfiguration, $persistenceConfiguration));
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes. But the repository object still use the value from storage pid TypoScript configuration. How can I update the storage pid of the repository object?

Comment: You'll have to modify this manually. Will update my answer on friday when I have access to my code again.

Comment: Thank you. I had to rework the example to math the new namespaces in Typo3 6, but it works.

Comment: pduersteler, thank you. Could you tell me if this is the right way, to channel the $pageId for Backend and Frontend?  

`if($GLOBALS['TSFE'] === NULL){  
   $this->pageId = (int) \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GP('id');  
}else{  
   $this->pageId = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->id;  
}
`